# What is intermediate directories in SVN?

Tags: svn

I just started to learn SVN. 
Please give me your advice to understand the basic theory below.

The `svn copy` and `svn move` command have an option called `--parents`.
It says without `--parents` option, it would not create `intermediate directories`.

Could anyone tell me what `intermediate directories` are?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Let’s say you just created a new Java project in Subversion. You now have an empty directory, and you want to create a directory for your source files. I like to follow Maven directory structure even if I’m not using Maven. Maven says my source files should be under the `src/main/java` directory. Since my company is VegiBank.com and this is their foundation project, I want to create the directory `src/main/java/com/vegibank/foundation`. I could do this:

```
$ svn mkdir src
$ svn mkdir src/main
$ svn mkdir src/main/java
$ svn mkdir src/main/java/com
$ svn mkdir src/main/java/com/vegibank
$ svn mkdir src/main/java/com/vegibank/foundation
```

I have to first create the directory in order to create the subdirectory. However, with the `--parents` option, I can replace all of those with a single command:

```
$ svn mkdir --parents src/main/java/com/vegibank/foundation
```

That makes the entire directory tree without me creating each single subdirectory one at a time.

Answer (score 6):

See [`mkdir -p`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/mkdir) for the functionality svn is mimicking.

```
svn cp foo bar/baz/foo
```

If `bar` or `bar/baz` do not exist then the copy will fail.

```
svn cp --parents foo bar/baz/foo
```

If `bar` and/or `bar/baz` do not exist then they'll be created automatically.