# maven scm - Does maven creates tag automatically?

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3, maven-release-plugin, maven-scm

I have below configurations in place -

```
<scm>
<connection>scm:svn:http://example.com/tags/MyProject/MyProject-0.1</connection>
<developerConnection>scm:svn:http://example.com/tags/MyProject/MyProject-0.1</developerConnection>
<url>scm:svn:http://example.com/tags/MyProject/MyProject-0.1</url>
</scm>
```

My question is each time version changes for my project above scm configurations will change. say from 0.1 to 0.2 and so on...
Do we need to make sure these tags created in svn or does maven creates the tag? if Maven creates the tag with my above configuration I already have http://example.com/tags/MyProject available but it's not tagging the  above?

Can anye fill me some thoughts please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the configuration is correct and you are using [maven-release-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/) which means

```
mvn release:prepare
```

than a SVN tag is created automatically by [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/examples/prepare-release.html). So there is no need to check. Apart from that it could happen that you need to change the tag-Base in the Maven-release-plugin if you have a different SVN layout which is not like:

```
   Repo
    +-- Project
            +--- trunk
            +--- tags
            +--- branches
```

which means you need to configure the [maven-release-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/usage.html):

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <tagBase>https://svn.mycompany.com/repos/myapplication/releases</tagBase>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
    ...
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

The svn copy and svn move command have an option called --parents. It says without --parents option, it would not create intermediate directories.

[What is intermediate directories in SVN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12906238/what-is-intermediate-directories-in-svn)

This is an issue which should be raised at
http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SCM